# What script to include for both Google Places and Geocoding

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoder

I'm struggling to get a Google Places lookup AND Geocoding to work together in the same page. I think there's a conflict in how I'm loading the two APIs.

I'm using this one to load the places API

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=*****************&callback=initAutocomplete&types=address" async defer></script>
```

Places lookup works fine with that.

For Geocoding, this is the first line of code I'm trying to get working

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

And it works (well, doesn't throw an error) if I include this in my page:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

But that's pretty much the same URL I already have, and including it breaks the Places lookup. When I have both scripts included I also get a warning telling me I've included the Maps API multiple times which may cause problems.

Please could someone show me which script(s) to include for both to work together? I'm finding the docs pretty confusing at this point to be honest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine with just your first include. It contains the base Google Maps API **plus** the Places library.

```js
var initMap = function () {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: '10 Downing St, Westminster, London SW1A 2AA, UK',
  }, function (results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      var result = results[0];
      alert('latitude: ' + result.geometry.location.lat());
    }
    else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Maarten, I've already got a callback on the include for the Places functionality, so I've modified your include to what I think should work for me:

Comment: Bear with me, I'm having a nightmare with the SO editor :)

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&types=address&key=*****************" async defer></script>

Comment: The Places search works fine with that, but when I get to the geocoding line (geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();) I get 'google is not defined' so for some reason, that include doesn't seem to be loading the Geocoding stuff

Comment: Make sure you only reference the google namespace after your callback has been called.

Comment: It works, thanks! I would never have guessed that, so many thanks for your help, you've saved me from a lot of frustration :)